# Interchangin ampersand and word and in search

Tags: solr

Can “&” and “and” work interchangebly like synonms when doing exact match “mac & cheese”

So for e.g

If i were to search mac & cheese, it matches

mac & cheese
mac-n-cheese
mac and cheese

It would be great if it did when I do exact match, q="mac & cheese".

Any suggestions?

Comment: hello, did you find a solution for this yet? regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess a [solr.SynonymFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) would work for you with:

& => and

Of course you have to make sure the tokenizers etc you use keep the & before reaching the synonymfilter